# iter through the dict store the key value and iter again to look for similar word in dict and delete form dict eg(Light1on,Light1off) in Python

Tags: python

[I had problem on how to iter through dict to find a pair of similar words and output it then the delete from dict]

1. My intention is to generate a random output label then store it into dictionary then iter through the dictionary and store the first key in the list or some sort then iter through the dictionary to search for similar key eg Light1on and Light1off has Light1 in it and get the value for both of the key to store into a table in its respective columns.
   such as 
   Dict = {Light1on,Light2on,Light1off...}
   store value equal to Light1on the iter through the dictionary to get eg Light1 off then store its Light1on:value1 and Light1off:value2 into a table or DF with columns name: On:value1 off:value2

   - As I dont know how to insert the code as code i can only provide the image sry for the trouble,its my first time asking question here thx.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import difflib, random

olist = []

input = 10
olist1 = ['Light1on','Light2on','Fan1on','Kettle1on','Heater1on']
olist2 = ['Light2off','Kettle1off','Light1off','Fan1off','Heater1off']
events = list(range(input + 1))

for i in range(len(olist1)):
  output1 = random.choice(olist1)
  print(output1,'1')
  olist1.remove(output1)
  output2 = random.choice(olist2)
  print(output2,'2')
  olist2.remove(output2)
  olist.append(output1)
  olist.append(output2)

print(olist,'3') 
outputList = {olist[i]:events[i]  for i in range(10)} 
print (str(outputList),'4')

# Iterating through the keys finding a pair match
for s in range(5):

  for i in outputList:

    if i == list(outputList)[0]:

      skeys = difflib.get_close_matches(i, outputList, n=2, cutoff=0.75)
      print(skeys,'5')
      del outputList[skeys]

# Modified Dictionary         
difflib.get_close_matches('anlmal', ['car', 'animal', 'house', 'animaltion'])
['animal']
```

- Updated: I was unable to delete the pair of similar from the list(Dictionary) after founding par in the dictionary

Comment: Please include your code in the post itself, not as an image.

Comment: Please include your code in the post

Comment: Also, image-related issues aside, could you provide some more information as to what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile i have added more detail on what i wanted as i used stackoverflow first time i can provide the picture for code reference sry for the trouble and hope you could help

Comment: @ZHLaw What I meant is can you include the code as **text** in your post?

Comment: Please don't use links. Copy and paste the code please

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I have updated the code and description i tried to change the code was still encountering some issues

Comment: Be careful, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting an error about a dictionary changing size during iteration. That's because you're deleting keys from a dictionary you're iterating over, and Python doesn't like that:

```
d = {1:2, 3:4}
for i in d:
  del d[i]
```

That will throw:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

To work around that, one solution is to store a list of the keys you want to delete, then delete all those keys after you've finished iterating:

```
keys_to_delete = []
d = {1:2, 3:4}
for i in d:
  if i%2 == 1:
    keys_to_delete.append(i)

for i in keys_to_delete:
  del d[i]
```

Ta-da! Same effect, but this way avoids the error.

Also, your code above doesn't call the `difflib.get_close_matches` function properly. You can use `print(help(difflib.get_close_matches))` to see how you are meant to call that function. You need to provide a second argument that indicates the items to which you wish to compare your first argument for possible matches.

All of that said, I have a feeling that you can accomplish your fundamental goals much more simply. If you spend a few minutes describing what you're really trying to do (this shouldn't involve any references to data types, it should just involve a description of your data and your goals), then I bet someone on this site can help you solve that problem much more simply!

Comment: Sure thing. This place can be a little strange to get used to but you'll like it once you do! To format code, you can place your code between ``` and ``` marks. Click "edit" under your question to see how I added those marks to your code to give it the highlighted look.

Comment: is it possible to delete pair i found from list(dictionary) and recorded into another df with 2 column with the first key's value in the pair in the column and second key's value in the pair of similarity in the other column.If you are able to help it will be fantastic thx in advance.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you @ZHLaw! I would open a new question...